# How to loop through array with arrays/objects and assign properties new values in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, object, for-loop

I have an array of arrays and objects. I have a function whereI want to assign a value to a property (so for example 'call':'' of $scope.companies[0].users becomes whatever value the user checks in the checkbox). I researched it and I just don't know how to do that and everything I did so far is wrong. Thanks a lot!!

```
      <form action="" ng-click="change(key)">
        <input ng-model="key.call"type="checkbox"">Call
        <br>
        <input ng-model="key.person"type="checkbox" >Person
        <br>
        <input type="checkbox"ng-model="key.dial">Dial
        <br>
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="key.voice">Voice          
    </form>

app.controller('appCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.companies = [{
        name: 'The Best Company Denim',
        users: [{
            firstName: 'Alex',
            lastName: 'D',
            number: 1234,
            call: '',
            person: '',
            dial: '',
            voice: ''
        }, {
            firstName: 'Sarah',
            lastName: 't',
            number: 14,
            call: '',
            person: '',
            dial: '',
            voice: ''
        }, {
            firstName: 'J',
            lastName: 'd',
            number: 07,
            call: '',
            person: '',
            dial: '',
            voice: ''
        }]
    }, {
        name: 'The Best Company Elegant',
        users: [{
            firstName: 'Alx',
            lastName: 'B',
            number: 1234,
            call: '',
            person: '',
            dial: '',
            voice: ''
        }, {
            firstName: 'Seth',
            lastName: 'w',
            number: 12,
            call: '',
            person: '',
            dial: '',
            voice: ''
        }, {
            firstName: 'J.S',
            lastName: 'B',
            number: 7.
            call: '',
            person: '',
            dial: '',
            voice: ''
        }]
    }, {
        name: 'The Best Company by Julia',
        users: [{
            firstName: 'Aleddddx',
            lastName: 'l',
            number: 1234,
            call: '',
            person: '',
            dial: '',
            voice: ''
        }, {
            firstName: 'Maggy',
            lastName: 'n',
            number: 1,
            call: '',
            person: '',
            dial: '',
            voice: ''
        }, {
            firstName: 'Ja',
            lastName: 'Key',
            number: 123,
            call: '',
            person: '',
            dial: '',
            voice: ''
        }]
    }]

    $scope.change = function(key) {
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.companies[0].users; i++) {
            $scope.companies[0].users[i].call: key)
    }
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the code above, `$scope.companies[0].users` is an array, which have a `length` property that gives you the number of items in it. Then your code will be:

> `$scope.change = function(key) {
>           for (var i = 0; i < $scope.companies[0].users.length; i++) {
>               $scope.companies[0].users[i].call = key;
>       }`

If you are looking for looping through companies too, then nest 2 for loops, one to loop companies and another one to loop users with the same idea given in above code.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer. The only thing I don't understand is, when I console.log $scope.companies[0].users[i]  and for example chose 'call' in the checkbox, it gives me an object (so call=object) instead of changing call="" to call=true.